# How to preview PDF file in internet explorer in MVC Web Application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I require to preview `PDF` file stored in database. In `Chrome` its working fine but when i do it in `IE` it gets downloaded. Reason may be due to below code:

Javascript Method:

```
if (navigator.appVersion.toString().indexOf('.NET') > 0) {
    console.log(response._body);
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(response._body, obj.documentName);
}
```

Controller Method:

```
[HttpGet]  
public FileResult DownLoadFile(int id)  
{  
    List<FileDetailsModel> ObjFiles = GetFileList();  
    var FileById = (from FC in ObjFiles  
                    where FC.Id.Equals(id)  
                    select new { FC.FileName, FC.FileContent }).ToList().FirstOrDefault();  
     return File(FileById.FileContent, "application/pdf", FileById.FileName);  
}
```

So is there way by which we can preview `PDF` file as all files are in `PDF` format in database.

Comment: "How to preview PDF file in internet explorer in MVC Web application" you mean ? Web API is another technology

Comment: Sorry for mistake. Yes it is MVC controller and it has DownloadFile method which returns File object. I am able to preview pdf in chrome but in IE it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for this. I converted word, excel and pdf documents in html version using SaveOptions in aspose and then can easily render html output in div or new window in IE

Answer (score 0):

A solution (that is surely not the best because iframe are deprecated) would be make an intermediate page framed to occupy 100% of parent page like :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="@Url.Action("DownLoadFile", new {id = 1})" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually i am using client side script to make http call to controller method and i get blob object as you see in above code. So is there any way to preview blob object in IE. Chrome works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have this snippet for you where we check browsers. I think you can use parts of it to fix your problem. Cross-browser file serving through javascript is sometimes a PITA.

use GGO's iframe suggestion but to generate the url use this code:

```
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

Comment: Thanks for response but as you can see in my question as well In case of IE  ,  "window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, file.name);"  code will download file in browser .It will not display pdf like Chrome does. Any suggestion ?

Comment: As GGO suggested, when using Iframe it should display it in the page as a preview, if of course Acrobat is installed...

Comment: I adjusted my answer with the method to create an url. Then set this to the url attribute of the iframe

Comment: Thanks but IE doesn't support createObjectURL .